# Swift 3: How to allow users to select multiple images from photo library?

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods

I believe this question have been asked more than a million times. But I still can't find the suitable multiple image picker library and able to view it. The most ideal imagepicker library I want is: https://github.com/yahoo/YangMingShan

The problem is I do not know how to install it as the only way to install it is via CocoaPods.

*This might be the easiest question* but I really have no idea on how to install frameworks/projects via CocoaPods.

*Or*

Is there any other ways to implement a multiple image picker for iPhone in Swift 3?

Any help is much appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to install frameworks/projects via CocoaPods ?

**Answer**

Try to [install](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html) `cocoaPods`:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Go to your project folder:

```
pod init
```

A file called podfile will be created in your project folder.
Edit that file:

```
pod 'YangMingShan'
```

After that run:

```
pod install
```

Remember to open the generated **workspace** file after that.

Comment: I've followed your instructions and used the generated workspace file after that but i still having errors like 'No such module' when i tried to import the 'YangMingShan' framework into my codes :\

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your workspace. Press command + shift + k and try running it again.